# What is the logic behind the <statement, setup> design for timeit?

Tags: python, debugging, timeit

I am new to Python and figured I'd play around with problems on Project Euler to have something concrete to do meanwhile.

I came across the idea of timing different solutions to see how they rate against each other. That simple task turned out to be too complicated for my taste however. I read that the `time.clock()` calls are not accurate enough on unix systems (seconds resolution is simply pathetic with modern processors). Thus I stumbled upon the `timeit` module which seems to be the first choice for profiling tasks.

I have to say I really don't understand why they went with such a counter-intuitive way to go about it. I can't seem to get it to work, without needing to rewrite/restructure my code, which I find very frustrating.

Take the code below and nevermind for a second that it's neither pretty nor particularly efficient:

```
import math
import sys
from timeit import Timer

def digitsum(number):
    rem = 0 
    while number > 0:
        rem += number % 10
        number //= 10
    return rem

def prime_form(p):
    if p == 2 or p == 3 or p == 5:
        return True
    elif (p-1) % 6 != 0 and (p+1) % 6 != 0:
        return False
    elif digitsum(p) % 3 == 0: 
        return False
    elif p % 10 == 0 or p % 10 == 5:
        return False
    else:
        return True

def lfactor(n):

    if n <= 3:
        return 1

    limit = int(math.sqrt(n))
    if limit % 2 == 0:
        limit -= 1

    lfac = 1
    for i in range(3,limit+1,2):
        if prime_form(i):
            (div,rem) = divmod(n,i)
            if rem == 0:
                lfac = max(lfac, max(lfactor(div) ,lfactor(i)))

    return lfac if lfac != 1 else n

number = int(sys.argv[1])
t = Timer("""print lfactor(number)""", """import primefacs""")
t.timeit(100)
#print lfactor(number)
```

If i would like to time the line `print lfactor(number)` why should I go through a bunch of loops, trying to define a setup statement etc.. I understand why one would want to have debug tool that are detached from the code being tested (a la unit testing) but shouldn't there be a simple and straightforward way to get the process time of a chunk of code without much hassle (importing/defining a setup etc)? What I am thinking here is something like the way one would do that:

```
long t0 = System.currentTimeInMillis();
// do something
long t = System.currentTimeInMillis() - t0;
```

.. or even better with MATLAB, using the tic/toc commands:

```
tic
x = A\b;
t(n) = toc;
```

Hope this doesn't come across as a rant, I am really trying understand "the pythonian way of thinking" but honestly it doesn't come naturally here, not at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When timing a statement, you want to time just that statement, not the setup. The setup could be considerably slower than the statement-under-test.

Note that `timeit` runs your statement thousands of times to get a reasonable average. It does this to eliminate the effects of OS scheduling and other processes (including but not limited to disk buffer flushing, cronjob execution, memory swapping, etc); only an average time would have any meaning when comparing different code alternatives.

For your case, just test `lfactor(number)` directly, and just use the `timeit()` function:

```
timeit.timeit('lfactor(number)', 'from __main__ import lfactor, number')
```

The setup code retrieves the `lfactor()` function, as well as `number` taken from `sys.argv` from the main script; the function and number won't otherwise be seen.

There is absolutely *no* point in performance testing the `print` statement, that's not what you are trying to time. Using `timeit` is *not* about seeing the result of the call, just the time it takes to run it. Since the code-under-test is run thousands of times, all you'd get is thousands of prints of (presumably) the same result.

Note that usually `timeit` is used to compare performance characteristics of short python snippets; to find performance bottlenecks in more complex code, use [profiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script) instead.

If you want to time just one run, use the `timeit.default_timer()` function to get the most accurate timer for your platform:

```
timer = timeit.default_timer
start = timer()
print lfactor(number)
time_taken = timer() - start
```

Comment: with respect to your comments about seeing the execution time of `print`, you see I originally had only that line to see what my algorithm does. In order to be able to print the result, the calculation needs to be carried out, which is what I wanted to time.

Comment: @posdef: your post contains `Timer("""print lfactor(number)""", """import primefacs""")`; you are including the `print` in the timing then. To run the calculation the result doesn't need to be printed. :-)

Comment: yes, i am aware of that, it was me being lazy and including the time `print` takes as well, mostly to not write an extra line of code i.e. `result = lfactor(number)` then `print result`. I don't think that choice of laziness should have much to do with how you time a chunk of code. Thanks for the reply anyways.

Comment: @posdef: That would not have worked; the `timeit` result is not stored. `timeit` will execute that line thousands of times to get an average timing, so retaining the result has no meaning. `timeit` is not meant to time a piece of code *once*, but to eliminate the influence of disk caches, cpu scheduling and other latencies in comparing multiple alternative implementations by averaging multiple runs, instead.

Comment: Alright, see that's a reason I can buy. If my use case is not what `timeit` is intended for I can understand the extra hassle. I would be very appreciative if you could edit your answer and add that bit information, I think it's very relevant to the core of the question here. :)

Answer (score 3):

Simple, the logic behind the statement and setup is that the setup is not part of the code you want to benchmark. Normally a python module is loaded once while the functions inside it are run more than one, much more.

A pythonic way of use `timeit`?

```
$ python -m timeit -h

Tool for measuring execution time of small code snippets.

This module avoids a number of common traps for measuring execution
times.  See also Tim Peters' introduction to the Algorithms chapter in
the Python Cookbook, published by O'Reilly.

Library usage: see the Timer class.

Command line usage:
    python timeit.py [-n N] [-r N] [-s S] [-t] [-c] [-h] [--] [statement]

Options:
  -n/--number N: how many times to execute 'statement' (default: see below)
  -r/--repeat N: how many times to repeat the timer (default 3)
  -s/--setup S: statement to be executed once initially (default 'pass')
  -t/--time: use time.time() (default on Unix)
  -c/--clock: use time.clock() (default on Windows)
  -v/--verbose: print raw timing results; repeat for more digits precision
  -h/--help: print this usage message and exit
  --: separate options from statement, use when statement starts with -
  statement: statement to be timed (default 'pass')

[cut]


$ python -m timeit -s 'from primefacs import lfactor' 'lfactor(42)'

$ # this does not work, primefacs is not binded, ie. not loaded
$ python -m timeit 'primefacts.lfactor(42)'


$ # this does not work too, lfactor is not defined
$ python -m timeit 'lfactor(42)'

$ # this works but the time to import primefacs is benchmarked too
$ # but only the first time is loaded, the successive ones the cache is used. 
$ python -m timeit 'import primefacts; primefacts.lfactor(42)'
```

As you can see, the way `timeit` works is much more intuitive than you think.

**Edit to add:**

> I read that the time.clock() calls are not accurate enough on unix
>   systems (seconds resolution is simply pathetic with modern
>   processors).

quoting the documentation:

> On Unix, return the current processor time as a floating point number
>   expressed in seconds. The precision, and in fact the very definition
>   of the meaning of “processor time”, depends on that of the C function
>   of the same name, but in any case, this is the function to use for
>   benchmarking Python or timing algorithms... The resolution is
>   typically better than one microsecond.

going on..

> I have to say I really don't understand why they went with such a
>   counter-intuitive way to go about it. I can't seem to get it to work,
>   without needing to rewrite/restructure my code, which I find very
>   frustrating.

Yes, it could be but then this is one of those cases where documentation can help you, here a link to the [examples](http://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) for the impatiens. Here a more [gentle introduction](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/timeit/index.html#module-timeit) to `timeit`.

Comment: Hmm, "much more intuitive than you think" is false by definition!  If you need an explanation for something, then it isn't intuitive.  Perhaps you mean, "it make a lot of sense once you understand the background."

Comment: I have to agree with @nedbatchelder if you need an explanation then it's not intuitive by definition. I can see the idea behind having a one-time setup. But it amazes me that there is no way of getting a quick readout on how fast something is executed, for crude debug efforts. I am talking about something along the lines of `System.getCurrentTimeInMillis()` in Java or `tic/toc` in MATLAB

Comment: @posdef: you can get the current time if that's what you want.

Comment: @nedbatchelder with what resolution is the real question there, if I could easily get time in millisec resolution or better, I would be fine with it, I think. My understanding is `time.clock()` returns in only second resolution, not milliseconds.

Comment: @NedBatchelder: yes that statement is a little bit unfortunate